# I dont understand the definition of the boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology

I saw this definition of a boundary of a set in a book.

> The boundary of $A\subseteq X$ is $(\overline{X\setminus A})\cap \bar{A}$

Now this does not make sense to me because does that not just mean the boundary is always empty?

Consider $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $A=\{4,5\}$

$X\setminus A=\{1,2,3\}$

$\overline{X\setminus A}=\{4,5\}$
this intersected with not A is  empty? So the boundary is always empty?

Comment: Use the command "overline", i.e., $\overline{X\setminus A}$.

Comment: The overline set $\overline{X\backslash A}$ is called the *closure* of the set, not the compliment. It is a consequence of topology.

Comment: Consider $A = [0, 1]$

Comment: You need to have some topology to define boundary.

Comment: @Josh "fishing for compliments"? The closure, and not  the complement.

Comment: In your interpretation of the definition, you treat $X\setminus A$ and $\overline{A}$ as the same thing. Since a book would probably not use two different notations in the very same definition, this is the first clue that $\overline{A}$ does not mean what you think in this context. Here $\overline{A}$ is the topological closure of the subset $A$. Thus there is a topology on $X$ which you need to understand in order to make sense of $\overline{A}$ in various examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by `@zkutch` you need to have a topology to define what a boundary is. But the boundary of A is the minimal set, whose union with the interior of A gives a closed set.

Assuming you are working with the discrete topology, then the singletons are closed, thus your A and its complement are both closed and open. Making the boundary empty. But the trivial topology is not always interesting.

Let's work with $\mathbb{R}$ and the standard topology. There the set $(0,1)$ is open and its closure is $[0,1]$, its complement is $(-\infty,0]$ and $[1,\infty)$ and is closed. Now intuitively one would say the boundary is 0 and 1, which is exactly what we get by intersecting both closures.

Comment: “But the boundary of A is the minimal set, whose union with A gives a closed set.” — That's not true. If it were, then the boundary of any closed set would be empty. However if you add as second requirement that removing it from $A$ (in the sense of set difference) gives an open set, then it works.

Comment: @celtschk You are right. I wanted to give an intuitive explanation and in that process failed to stay accurate. Thank you, I will correct it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, +1